# Rails View Encoding Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 3.2.14. My view is littered several UTF-8 characters, mainly currency symbols like บาท and د.إ etc. I noticed some

```
(ActionView::Template::Error) "incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

in our production code and promptly tried visiting the page url on my browser without any issues. On digging in, I realised the error was actually caused by BingBot and few spiders. So when I tried to curl the same url, I was able to reproduce the issue. So, if I try

```
curl http://localhost:3000/?x=✓
```

I get the error where UTF-8 symbols are used in the view code. I also realised that if use HTML encoded strings in place of the symbols, this does not occur. However, I prefer using the actual symbols.

And I have already tried setting Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8 in environment.rb adding #encoding: utf-8 magic comment to top of file and it does not help.

So, why does this error occur? What is the difference between hitting this url on browser and on CURL besides cookies? And how do I go about fixing this issue and allow BingBot to index our site? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit that was leaking non UTF-8 characters in my template was an innocuous meta tag for Facebook Open Graph

```
%meta{property: "og:url", content: request.url}
```

And when the request is non-standard, this causes the encoding issue. Changing it to

```
%meta{property: "og:url", content: request.url.force_encoding('UTF-8')}
```

made the trick.

Answer (score 2):

That error message usually occurs when you try to concatenate strings with different character encodings.

Is your database set to use UTF-8 as well?

If not, you could have a problem when you try to insert the non-UTF8 values into your UTF-8 template.

Comment: Yes, I'm using postgres and my database encoding is also UTF8. You're totally right in that non-UTF8 values in UTF-8 cause this but it was not the database in my case.